# PowerShell Remove-Item can't handle junctions

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell-v3.0

Windows Server 2012 using PowerShell to create a log file in the temp folder:

```
$LogFile = $env:temp + "\MigrateMyDocs.log"
```

Let's say one's script has already run and you want to delete the log file at the start of the script using something like this:

```
If (Test-Path($LogFile)) {
    [void](Remove-Item -Path $LogFile -Force)
}
```

It doesn't work as `Remove-Item` seems to bolsh on the AppData function in `$LogFile`:

```
"C:\Users\IT0A9D~1.SUP\AppData\Local\Temp\1\MigrateMyDocs.log"
```

Seems a bit brain dead of `Remove-Item` to not understand junctions (AppData). Is there anyway around this?

Comment: That seems to work here. What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Remove-item throws an error saying it can't remove the document. It's well documented that Remove-Item doesn't seem to be able to handle junctions which is what one gets with AppData on Windows 7 et al

Comment: You aren't asking it to remove the junction though. You are asking it to remove a file beneath a junction, no? (Assuming AppData is a junction). Regardless I ran exactly those commands on both my Win 7 laptop and Server2012 machines and it worked correctly. (After having created the file from powershell with Set-Content.) Can powershell remove other (non-temp) files under that user directory? Is the truncated/mangled user name perhaps an issue?

Comment: All I can say is that it doesn't work for me. Here's a screenshot of the PS commands actually run on a different server http://www.picpaste.com/54ab28a559efba9a5cebba1b9e76a72f.png

Comment: And another screenshot to show the log file certainly does exist but remove-item can't delete it http://www.picpaste.com/733479590e7e1b05a8b020d1ee280f6d.png

Comment: What does 'Resolve-Path $LogFile' say? That error looks like an issue with the mangle user name directory rather than the final file. Also note the directory listed in the `dir` output differs from the contents of the variable. Are you setting temp manually by any chance? If not do you know why it is being set to that mangled version?

Comment: $Env:Temp returns the short path version so it's using that format from the very start. If I change the path manually to the long format, the item does indeed remove. So the problem here appears to be Remove-Item working with short paths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, with Etan's help above, I've got a workaround. $env:Temp returns a short file name path which works for lots of things *except* **Remove-Item**. So the workaround is to use GetFullPath to convert it into a long path, which Remove-Item can then use:

This doesn't work:

```
$LogFile = $Env:Temp + "\Test.log"
"Hello, World" > $LogFile
Remove-Item $LogFile
```

This does work:

```
$LogFile =  [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($env:Temp + "\Test.log")
"Hello, World" > $LogFile
Remove-Item $LogFile
```